# Android not showing SQL Query Results

Tags: java, android, sql

I am fairly new to Android Development and am currently working on an application to calculate one's GPA. I've been trying to show the GPA for each semester but so far my query is not working.

The code to list out the GPA for each semester: DISPLAYALLSEMESTERACTIVITY.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.markymark.ca2.R.id.listView1;

public class DISPLAYALLSEMESTERACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity {
DataManager sqLiteHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Cursor cursor;
GPAListAdapter listAdapter ;
ListView LISTVIEW;
String SEMHOLDER;

ArrayList<String> ID_Array;
ArrayList<String> GPA_Array;
ArrayList<String> SEMESTER_Array;
Intent intent;

ArrayList<String> ListViewClickItemArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String TempHolder ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_displayallsemesteractivity);

    LISTVIEW = (ListView) findViewById(listView1);
    intent = getIntent();
    SEMHOLDER = intent.getStringExtra("SEM");

    ID_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    GPA_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    SEMESTER_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    sqLiteHelper = new DataManager(this);

    LISTVIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


/*                Intent intent = new 
Intent(getApplicationContext(),DISPLAYONEGRADEACTIVITY.class);

            intent.putExtra("ListViewClickedItemValue", ListViewClickItemArray.get(position).toString());

            startActivity(intent);*/


        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {



    super.onResume();
    ShowSQLiteDBdata() ;
}

private void ShowSQLiteDBdata() {

    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) AS Semestergpa, Semester FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +" group by Semester", null);

    ID_Array.clear();
    SEMESTER_Array.clear();

    GPA_Array.clear();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {



 /*              ID_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataManager.Table_Column_ID)));*/

            //Inserting Column ID into Array to Use at ListView Click Listener Method.
/*                



ListViewClickItemArray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataManager.Table_Column_ID)));*/

GPA_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Semestergpa")));

            SEMESTER_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataManager.Table_Column_5_SEMESTER)));



        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    listAdapter = new GPAListAdapter(DISPLAYALLSEMESTERACTIVITY.this,

            ID_Array,
            GPA_Array,
            SEMESTER_Array
    );

    LISTVIEW.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    cursor.close();
}
}
```

My List Adapter: GPAListAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GPAListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<String> ID;
ArrayList<String> GPA;

ArrayList<String> SEMESTER;



public GPAListAdapter(
        Context context2,
        ArrayList<String> id,
        ArrayList<String> gPA,
        ArrayList<String> sEMESTER
)
{

    this.context = context2;
    this.ID = id;

    this.SEMESTER = sEMESTER;
    this.GPA = gPA;
}

   public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ID.size();
    }

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gpaitems, null);

        holder = new Holder();

 /*                holder.IDTextView = (TextView) 
child.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);*/
        holder.GPATextView = (TextView) 
child.findViewById(R.id.textViewGPA);
        holder.SEMESTERTextView = (TextView) 
child.findViewById(R.id.textViewSEMESTER);

        child.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    /*        holder.IDTextView.setText(ID.get(position));*/
    holder.GPATextView.setText(GPA.get(position));
    holder.SEMESTERTextView.setText(SEMESTER.get(position));

    return child;
}

public class Holder {

    TextView IDTextView;
    TextView GPATextView;
    TextView SEMESTERTextView;
}

}
```

Could someone explain what I've done wrong and how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your rawQuery returns the result?

try this code:

```
while  (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
       Log.d(LOG_TAG,"_id = +cursor.getString(catList.getColumnIndex("_id")));
       cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

to check the result

Comment: I am able to print out the results of the rawquery in logcat.

Comment: My Output is as follows:                                                                                                                                                                          

0 {
                                                                             Semestergpa=3.75
                                                                             SEMESTER=1
                                                                          }

Comment: Hello, I am able to print out the information I needed. I realised that I should have kept the statements to get the unique id and ran an sql query to get the id values. Thank you :)